# Solution verification for finding parametric equation of a line

Tags: projective-geometry

I have the following problem in $E_3^*$

I have to find a parametric equation of a line passing through the point $M(3,1,2,1)$ and the infinite point of of a line **$l$** formed from two planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$$
\alpha: x+y=0\\\beta: y+z-t=0
$$

What I've got:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y=0 \\ 
y+z-t=0 \\ 
t=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

From there I find the coordinates of the point $U_l$ to be $(-1,1,-1,0)$ and the parametric equation of a line passing $U_l$ and M to be

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=3\lambda-\mu \\ 
y=1\lambda+\mu \\ 
z=2\lambda-1\mu\\
t=1\lambda+0\mu
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Is this the correct approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is this $$M(3,1,2,1)$$?

Comment: coordinates of the point $M$